# ImportError: No module named selenium windows cmd

Tags: python, selenium

So I am getting this error and I have already installed selenium through my requirements file. But I still have this error. Is there anything I can do about it?
I have also tried `pip install selenium` separately.
Please help.

Error is shown here `from selenium import webdriver`

Python and pip versions:

```
C:\Users\hp>python --version
Python 2.7.18 :: Anaconda, Inc.
C:\Users\hp>pip --version
pip 20.2.4 from c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

```
import time, random, os, csv, platform
import logging
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import pyautogui

from urllib.request import urlopen
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import re
import yaml
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: Did you install the package in the same library? Are you using a virtual environment? Also in some systems there may be multiple python lib files (eg. python2 or 3). Please provide pertinent information.

Comment: I am sorry I am very new, I have installed in the same library for sure as it is the same way I installed my other packages that were throwing an error. I have a file that contains all the codes and an asset folder for selenium webdriver and I downloaded requirements through requirements file. I am using the cmd in my windows and using code ```python filename.py```, was this any helpful?

Comment: So just to clarify your other packages work fine? also what's the first import statement in filename.py? When you say downloaded requirements through requirement file, can you pls elaborate? Have you setup a virtual environment? Which version of python are you using? (Please try to include these info in your question)

Comment: I am using **Python 2.7.18**.Yes other packages work fine. I have updated my import part. I have a file with all the requirements as requirements.txt.

Comment: Update the question to show us the output of these commands: `python --version` and `pip --version`

Comment: done!!! please check

Comment: seems like your pip is pointing to Python3.9. You should try running your code as python3 filename.py

Comment: I get this ```python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```

Comment: Can you try my answer.. just py filename.py?

Comment: answerd shows a similar error

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a mismatch between `python` and `pip`. Your `pip` is pointing to `python3` whereas `python` uses default `python2` system package.

Try running your code using the command `py filename.py`

**UPDATE 1:** If the path for python3 is not setup properly you may get the missing package issue. Based on the link from your pip version can you try this:

```
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python filename.py
```

**UPDATE 2:** If you do not have python3 and need to revert pip to the right version.

You can download the [get_pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) file and run it using:

```
python get_pip.py
```

(navigate to the correct directory where get_pip is stored)

Later check your pip version using `pip --version`. Hopefully it will now point to Python2. If it does, you should now be able install selenium and other requirements to the correct version of python and run your code.

Comment: I get this error ```'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```

Comment: which version of windows are you using? The above command works for me fine (Must have come with default python installation)

Comment: Windows 10 pro to be precise

Comment: OK my guess is that you do not have python3 but wrongly installed pip for python3. You need to reinstall pip to fix this issue. (Does pip install selenium work normally? what's the output of "pip show selenium"?

Comment: It shows selenium is already present at the specific location

Comment: Yes but my question is, what is that location?

Comment: ohh sorry,                                                                                          ```C:\Users\hp>pip install selenium
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.9)```

Comment: you can try the pip installation technique shared in the answer... If that does not help you may need to install python 3.

Comment: get-pip does not work either.Still gives the same location So shall I delete all python and give it a fresh start with python3 you suggest ? Shall I share the code I am running I found it on github

Comment: I guess so. There is plenty of docs available on python installation. Python2 is also no longer supported. So it's best to migrate to python 3 and start from there.

Comment: Thanks I had miniconda 2 I deleted that and it works now. But I am stuck with the code now

Comment: If you are stuck with the code and have a different error you can post that as a different question.